# OCaml list flattening using a recursive function

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, flatten

I am trying to get a recursive function to flatten lists where I am not allowed a helper function. I can only use @. And I'm trying to use "match with"

I tried this way

```
let rec flatten lst1 = match lst1 with 
  | [] -> []
  | hd::tl -> hd @ (flatten tl);;

flatten [[3; 4]; [4; 5]];;
```

the result was a stack overflow

(I just switched `flatten lst1` with `flatten tl` and it works. Thanks)

Comment: Note that this function is already implemented in the standard library as `List.concat`

Answer (score 2):

Don't ignore compiler warnings:

```ml
let[@warning "+a"] rec flatten lst1 = match lst1 with 
 |[] -> []
 |hd::tl -> hd @ (flatten lst1);;
```

> ```
> |  |hd::tl -> hd @ (flatten lst1);;
>         ^^
> Warning 27 [unused-var-strict]: unused variable tl.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You feed your recursive function with the same list. Try calling your recursive function with your tail

```
let rec flatten lst1 = match lst1 with 
 |[] -> []
 |hd::tl -> hd @ (flatten tl);;

 flatten [[3;4];[4;5]];;

> [3; 4; 4; 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `@`. You can do it just with `::`. You just need to handle three conditions:

- The list is entirely empty. This provides an exit case for your recursion.
- The first element in the list is an empty list, in which case you just need to flatten the tail of the list.
- The first element is not an empty list. In that case you cons that first element onto the result of flattening the rest of the nested list.

```
let rec flatten lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | []::tl -> flatten tl
  | (x::xs)::tl -> x :: flatten (xs :: tl)
```

```
flatten [[3; 4]; [4; 5]]
3 :: flatten [[4]; [4; 5]]
3 :: 4 :: flatten [[]; [4; 5]]
3 :: 4 :: flatten [[4; 5]]
3 :: 4 :: 4 :: flatten [[5]]
3 :: 4 :: 4 :: 5 :: flatten [[]]
3 :: 4 :: 4 :: 5 :: flatten []
3 :: 4 :: 4 :: 5 :: []
[3; 4; 4; 5]
```

Apply [`tail_mod_cons`](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/tail_mod_cons.html) and this can become tail-recursive without any auxiliary function being required.